# Unable to query full dataset

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to get the results from the max dataset limit till I'm allowed to but when I set my limit it is only querying limited dataset.

In my case which is #This query will process 238.2 MB when run.#

How to maximize this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Rudalf, Welcome to SO. Not 100% sure what you are asking. Can you provide the exact query you are running and maybe a screenshot with more details

Comment: Normally people optimize their query to process **less** data, but seems you want to do the opposite. I'm interested to know why.